# MySQL Search page number from query

Tags: mysql, search

This is probably a common question but I am not even sure if I did the right search.

I have a pretty big query that returns a lot of data from differents tables in a certain order and filtred by some clauses. I put this in a table loading 100 rows per page. For this I use something like this:

```
SELECT lot_of_data_columns 
FROM many_tables 
WHERE many_clauses 
ORDER BY some_column DESC 
LIMIT (page_number * 100), 100
```

Now I want to implement a search field to look up for a value in a certain column. If this value exist, it will load the page that contains that row. I only want the page of the first apparition of the value.

I was thinking in something like this to get the row number in the order that is shown:

```
SELECT row 
FROM (    BIG_QUERY, 
          @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row 
          FROM table, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
     ) t
WHERE MATCH (column)
AGAINST ('value' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 1
```

It works, but only with some columns and rows, in others it just dont return anything even if the value exist.

Any suggestions? Maybe i'm getting a little ravel with my querys. Is there a easier solution?

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be some searched values. I have some values like this:

```
203-21
201-434
343-23
```

The **MATCH** ignores special chars, like the '-', and ignores too what comes next, so the word lenght is less than 4, that is the minimum word lenght for the **MATCH**. The solution is change the **ft_min_word_len** value in the **my.conf** file. Or removing the special chars from the searched value with:

```
REPLACE(column, '-', '_')
```

I still would like an easier solution to all this. If someone have a better idea would be great.

**UPDATE 2**

Instead of **MATCH - AGAINST** I changed to **REGEXP**. Something like this:

```
SELECT row 
FROM (    BIG_QUERY, 
          @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row 
          FROM table, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
     ) t
WHERE (column REGEXP '.*value.*')=1
LIMIT 1
```

And it's already working fine. But I'm a little worried about perfomance when increase the number of rows. I'll select the answer of someone who knows how to optimise my query.

Comment: you want to keep the pages normally, but just display the page where the search result can be found on (say page 3)

Comment: Yep, that's it, there's some function or something to get that?